# Picking a random point from a circle in 3D

Tags: analytic-geometry

I have a circle that is given by $ 
    \begin{cases}
        (x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2 + z^2 = 36\\
        4x + y - z - 9 = 0
    \end{cases}
 $ , and i need to take a point that belongs to this circle. Is there an easier way in general to find a point without randomly try to pick $x,y$ and $z$ until somehow they fit the equation?

Comment: What about the distribution of random points? Has it to be uniform on the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I use [wolframalpha.com](https://wolframalpha.com) [for equations like this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-3%29%5E2%20%2B%20%28y-4%29%5E2%20%2B%20z%5E2%20%3D%2036%3B%204x%20%2By%20-z%20%3D%209).
Actually, a better equation to input is [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-3%29%5E2%20%2B%20%28y-4%29%5E2%20%2B%20%284x%20%2B%20y%20-%209%29%5E2%20%3D%2036).

What you're looking for is something like $f(x)=y$ and $f(x,y)=z$.

Here's how I approach this specific system of equations:

1. Because the 3 squared terms always add up to 36, each term actually can be anywhere from 0 to 6. You can visualize this; it's every point on the surface of a sphere.

This means that z can be any value from -6 to 6, y any value from -2 to 10, and x any value from -3 to 9. This is called the "domain" of the surface.

2. The two equations can be combined to see the shadow of the circle on the x and y coordinate grid:

$(x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2 + (4x + y - 9)^2 = 36$

another way to write this is:

$17 x^2 + x (8 y - 78) + 2 y^2 - 26 y = -70$

I can also solve for y, so that I have y=f(x):

$y = f(x) = 0.5(-sqrt(-18x^2 + 52x + 29) - 4x + 13)$

I can also solve the first equation for z, so that I have z=f(x,y):

$z = sqrt(-1((x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2 - 36))$

All I did was I took the second equation, solved for z, and substituted back into the first equation. Then I simplified, then I solved for y.

It's also important to realize that I could have solved your second equation for x or y as well, and then substituted that back into the first equation. I just picked z because it had no coefficients so it was easier to solve for.

3. Now that we have an equation with 2 variables, x and y, we can pick an x within the domain and solve for a y. The domain of the 3D circle is different from the domain of the sphere, because it's on a slant. We can find the domain for x by looking at the y=f(x) equation from (2):

Find the roots of $-18x^2 + 52x + 29$:

$x = 1/18 (26 (+/-) sqrt(1198))$

This means x can be anywhere between $(26 - sqrt(1198))/18$ and $(26 + sqrt(1198))/18$.

To find a value to pick, I'll just use $x = (26 + 10)/18 = 36/18 = 2$.

- $x=2$
- $y = (5/2) -(sqrt(61)/2)$
- $z = sqrt(-(x-6)x - (y-8)y + 11)$

In summary, what I did was:

1. Use algebra to reduce the number of variables in an equation I'm working with
2. Solve equations for y=f(x) and z=f(x,y)
3. Find the domain of x, and pick an x in that domain
4. Plug x in y=f(x), solve for y, then plug y in z=f(x,y) and solve for z.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do that, but I think fundamentally they are doing the same thing. One way to do it: you can do a rotation, translation, scaling so that the plane becomes e.g. the $x$-$y$ plane, and the sphere becomes the unit sphere. Then sample a point in the 2-d unit circle (in your example, the circle could be $\{(x, y, z): z = 0,\,x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$) by e.g. sample an angle. After you get a sample, to the reverse rotation, translation, scaling to get a sample from the original circle.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $n={(4,1,-1)\over3\sqrt{2}}$ is the unit vector normal to the plane. We can choose two perpendicular unit vectors parallel to the plane as follows:
$$
u={(-1,4,0)\over\sqrt{17}},\quad v=n\times u={(-4,1,17)\over3\sqrt{34}}.
$$
The center $C$ of the circle is [that point on the plane which is nearest to the center](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2385433/vectors-planes) $(3,4,0)$ of the sphere:
$$
C=\left({13\over9},{65\over18},{7\over18}\right).
$$
Pythagoras' theorem gives then the radius of the circle:
$$
r=\sqrt{599\over18}.
$$

It follows that a generic point on the circle can be parameterised as:
$$
P=C+ru\cos t+rv\sin t,\quad t\in[0,2\pi).
$$

For a uniform distribution, just pick $t$ uniformly at random and substitute into the above formula.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you still need to solve the system of equations to find the two variables in terms of the other variable.

From the second equation we have $z=4x+y-9$ and substituting into the first gives

$$(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2+(4x+y-9)^2=36$$
$$\implies 2y^2+(8x-26)y+17x^2-78x+70=0.$$

Then fixing $x=c$ we obtain a quadratic for $y$, and applying the quadratic formula we have

$$y=\frac{1}{2}\left(\pm\sqrt{-18c^2+52c+29}-4c+13\right)$$

and substituting in $z$ gives $$z = \frac{1}{2}\left(\pm\sqrt{-18c^2+52c+29}+4c-5\right)$$

Note that $-18c^2+52c+29\geq0\iff\frac{1}{18}(26-\sqrt{1198}) (\approx -0.478)\leq c\leq \frac{1}{18}(26+\sqrt{1198})(
\approx 3.367),$ which is the range of values of $x$ for which you have real solutions.

Thus choosing any $x=c$ for $c$ in the given range above, you can obtain $y$ and $z$ by substituting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) $r, \phi, \theta$ transformation, and you'll have a "cube", where all values within it are within your sphere.
This way you choose $x,y,z$ in your ranges.

Comment: How do you know that this coordinate change transforms the *uniform* distribution of the sphere into the *uniform* distribution of the parallelepiped?

Comment: I don't see any constraint that the distribution has to be uniform.

Comment: While the problem title does reference "randomly", the problem text really does not. So I would interpret 'randomly' in this context as merely 'arbitrary'.

Comment: @NatanZB: Indeed, it is not explicitly mentioned, but this is the crux of the problem - otherwise you just pick a point, and that's it (i.e. you choose two coordinates, solve the equations and get the third coordinate). If the probability distribution is not specified, it is understood to be the usual one - i.e. the uniform one. And I was mistaken - it is not the uniform distribution on the *sphere*, but on the given *circle*. I agree, though, that the question is poorly formulated (someone asked for clarifications in a comment).